# How to get __lt__() to sort

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

```
class City:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self._string = string.split(',')
        self._name = self._string[0]
        self._state = self._string[1]
        self._latitude = self._string[2]
        self._longitude = self._string[3]
        self._location = [self._latitude, self._longitude]

    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def location(self):
        return self._location
        self.hand.sort(key=lambda x: x.longitude)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self._longitude < other._longitude:
            return True
        if self._longitude > other._longitude:
            return False
        if self._longitude == other._longitude:
            if self._latitude < other._latitude:
                return True
            if self._latitude > other._latitude:
                return False

citystrings = ["Charleston,WV,38.35,81.63",
              "Charlotte,NC,35.23,80.83",
              "Cheyenne,WY,41.15,104.87",
              "Chicago,IL,41.83,87.62",
              "Cincinnati,OH,39.13,84.50",
              "Cleveland,OH,41.47,81.62",
              "Columbia,SC,34.00,81.03",
              "Columbus,OH,40.00,83.02",
              "Dallas,TX,32.77,96.77",
              "Denver,CO,39.75,105.00"]
westtoeastnames = [
            "Denver",
            "Cheyenne",
            "Dallas",
            "Chicago",
            "Cincinnati",
            "Columbus",
            "Charleston",
            "Cleveland",
            "Columbia",
            "Charlotte",
          ]
cities = [City(s) for s in citystrings]
cities.sort()
sortednames = [c.name() for c in cities]
print(sortednames)
print(westtoeastnames)
['Cheyenne', 'Denver', 'Charlotte', 'Columbia', 'Cleveland', 'Charleston', 'Columbus', 'Cincinnati', 'Chicago', 'Dallas']
['Denver', 'Cheyenne', 'Dallas', 'Chicago', 'Cincinnati', 'Columbus', 'Charleston', 'Cleveland', 'Columbia', 'Charlotte']
```

This code tries to use `__lt__()` to sort the cities by how far they are west and the longitudes are based west of the prime meridian. I wrote an `__lt__()` method in the class but the `citystrings` won't sort to the correct order.

Comment: Show how you've tried to sort.

Comment: Could you please write down an example on how are you using this method? And it would also be helpful to see the incorrect output

Comment: If your function is comparing cities and sorting them, I would write the def __lt()__ method outside of the class, as it is an operation on a higher level

Comment: Don't know if it is relevant but the ```location``` method has a statement after a ```return``` statement - it will never execute.

Comment: Note that *numbers* have a different order than strings! You should convert latitude/longitude to `float`s: self._latitude = float(self._string[2])`.

Comment: In addition to to Martinj's answer, if you want to sort west-to-east (larger latitude first), then use `cities.sort(reverse=True)`.

Answer (score 6):

You are comparing your longitude and latitude as *strings*, not numbers. They are therefor compared lexicographically, not numerically, so `'104'` will sort *before* `'80'` because `'1'` comes before `'8'` in the ASCII table (it doesn't matter what other characters follow).

Convert your values to floating point numbers:

```
self._latitude = float(self._string[2])
self._longitude = float(self._string[3])
```

Your comparison has a small bug; if both longitude and latitude match, you return `None` instead of `False`. You *may* want to test for equality and apply the [`@functools.total_ordering()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) rather than assume that only `__lt__()` is called.

Cleaning up the code a little (and removing the `name()` and `location()` methods, just use `name` and `location` attributes):

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class City:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.name, self.state, lat, long = string.split(',')
        self.location = (self._latitude, self._longitude) = float(lat), float(long)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, City):
            return NotImplemented
        # tuples defer ordering to the contents; compare them
        # in (longitude, latitude) order so that if longitude is 
        # equal, the outcome is based on latitude.
        return self.location[::-1] < other.location[::-1]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, City):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.location == other.location
```

Note that `__lt__()` really only needs to compare `self.location`; tuple ordering takes care of the rest:

```
sortednames = [c.name for c in sorted(map(City, citystrings), reverse=True)]
```

Note the `reverse=True`; you want the larger values (further west from Greenwich) to be listed first.

Comment: DING DING DING. Wow thanks, I couldn't understand why it wouldn't work!